# Testing a component whose child has a context

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, antd, recompose

I am using the `antd Checkbox` component in my `CheckboxWidget` component, the component [has a `contextType` defined](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/checkbox/Checkbox.tsx#L33):

```
static contextTypes: {
   checkboxGroup: any
}
```

I would like to test it using `shallow` rendering with enzyme, so I am using the `withContext` helper from `recompose` inside the `beforeEach` block:

```
describe('Simple Checkbox Widget', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    withContext({
      getChildContext: function () {
        return {checkboxGroup: null}
      },
      childContextTypes: {
        checkboxGroup: shape({
          disabled: bool,
          toggleOption: func,
          value: array
        })
      }
    })(CheckboxWidget)
  })
})
```

However, when I write my test like this:

```
it('renders a checkbox from Antd', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Subject />)
  const actual = wrapper.find(AntdCheckbox).length
  const expected = 1
  expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
})
```

I notice that the test is failing because it cannot find the `Checkbox` widget. I think it is because the rendered component will look like:

```
 <Subject />
```

I found that the `wrapper.instance()` is `Subject` and `wrapper.instance().children` is undefined. I tried to use `wrapper.dive` but it does not seem to be working on the `wrapper.instance()` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way to put something in to the context. The `shallow` function accepts options as a second parameter. In the options you can pass the context for the component:

```
it('renders a checkbox from Antd', () = > {
  const wrapper = shallow( < Subject / > , {
    context: {
      checkboxGroup: checkboxGroup: shape({
        disabled: bool,
        toggleOption: func,
        value: array
      })
    }
  })
  const actual = wrapper.find('AntdCheckbox').length
  const expected = 1
  expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
})
```

Comment: I converted my tests using `mount(<Comp />, mountOptions)` to `shallow(<Comp />, shallowOptions)` with shallowOptions being the options you provided. Thank you